# How pinterest managed to load an iframe on any website when their extension is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop an extension similar to that of Pinterest's PinIt extension for google chrome.
 
In general, i know that loading any URL in an iframe which is not from the same origin would result in giving an error **"Refused to display 'https://www.someWebsite.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'."**
However, i do see that Pinterest is loading a URL on any website when using their extension. For Example, i was using the extension on instagram.com (i've used it on other sites as well) and then i took a screenshot [image]of what i could not understand. (Please refer to selected area in DOM)
Can anyone tell me how this can be achieved or probably how pinterest is doing this?

Comment: That's not correct, you can load any URL in an iframe, there is no crossorigin restriction here. What you can't do is to access the document of the iframe with JavaScript if it's from another domain.

Comment: @TiborSzaszOk, if that's the case then how is pinterest accessing the images of the webpage? Any idea? Btw, i tried to load the iframe via extension i'm developing and the error i've mention is what i saw.

Comment: @TiborSzasz For an experiment, try to load Google Search inside an iframe. `X-Frame-Options` is a thing.

Comment: @Tushar Shukla With a chrome extension you can inject any JS to the page and you won't run into crossdomain issues.

Comment: @TiborSzasz I know i can inject, i have successfully completed development of my extension as well but without the use of iFrame. But i do need to do it with iframe in which case, i cannot access data from the parent window. My simple query is HOW PINTEREST IS ACHIEVING THIS WHOLE THING OF CAPTURING IMAGEs AND THEN DISPLAYING THOSE IN AN IFRAME.

Comment: I can read lowercase characters too ;) They don't access your page via JavaScript. They MUST (you probably need this all caps emphasis) use a backend server to fetch your page and display the found images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to deal with this. I still do not know how exactly  pinterest is doing it but i'm sure i'm close to it.
I simply load an iframe in the body of the parent by injecting my own JS to the page.
Then i iterate through all the images available on the page like

```
$('img).each(function(){
    // do my stuff to see if i need this image
    // push them in an array (say, var imgArray)
})
    var imgToString = imgArray.toString();
    var myIframe = document.getElementById('iframe_id').contentWindow;
    myIframe..postMessage(imgToString , '*');
```

And then in the iFrame that i load, i recieve the message and use the images...
So the gist of the whole issue is that `postMessage()` is my saviour.

Answer (score 1):

`X-Frame-Options` dictate which frames can **embed** the page, not which pages can **be embedded in it**.

So if, say, `https://www.someWebsite.com/` disallows to be embedded, `X-Frame-Options` doesn't prevent embedding `https://www.someOtherWebsite.com/` inside it (if the other website allows it).

However, [`child-src` or `frame-src` Content Security Policy directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/CSP/CSP_policy_directives#child-src) *can* prevent embedding another page.

---

In theory, both mechanisms can be be overridden by `webRequest` API. However:

1. PinIt doesn't use it, so logically it should fail on some sites.
   http://content-security-policy.com/ is an example where it simply fails.
2. There may be additional countermeasures if you decide to circumvent response headers.
   It's a cat and mouse game if some resource is unwilling to be embedded or allow embeds.
3. By changing CSP headers, you are weakening security considerably for your users.

Comment: Well then in this case, we still do not know how Pinterest is doing this. And i have used Pin It button on almost all major sites in my knowledge and it works everywhere..... Any suggestions pal?

Comment: "How" is answered by a look at the source. It's partly minified but commented. Pin It injects a `<script>` tag into the page via `executeScript` that loads code from their CDN, and it does the rest, including creating a frame. This whole process fails on pages with strict CSP, regardless of whether you personally observed it or not. I have an explicit example where it fails.